# Python animation using matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I've been browsing docs, examples, and SO questions for hours now and still am unable to figure this out .
I have the following python function:

```
def getPlotData(index)
```

Which returns 4 lists:

```
tPlots, yPlots, colorPlots, alphaPlots
```

Each element in each list contains

- a set of t values (or independent values)
- a set of y values (dependent values)
- a color (e.g. `'#00FF00'`)
- an alpha (e.g. `.5`)

such that I could make individual image plots as such:

```
N = 100 #the details of how i have this number aren't important.
for frame in range(N):
    tPlots, yPlots, colorPlots, alphaPlots = getPlotData(frame)
    for i in range(len(tPlots)):
        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(tPlots[i],yPlots[i],color=colorPlots[i], alpha = alphaPlots[i])

plt.show()
```

but this of course generates static figures, one per frame. I would like to generate a movie from these frames, but the API for `matplotlib` is very confusing to me for animations/movies. There are many options to choose from and none seem simple. None of the ways seem inherently organized the way my functions produce frames. I've refactored `getPlotData(index)` 3 times now to try to get function usable by some of the `matplotlib` methods to no avail, although the currently 3rd-refactored form is the most useable (most modular).

The simplest approach seemed to be if I could just create a `list` of frames, but I have yet to succeed applying the above `getPlotData(index)` to this use case even from following [this example](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/examples/animation/basic_example.html).

Any ideas? 
Thank you.

EDIT: I just wanted to be clear, my intent is to save the movie to an mp4 or any other file format. I don't intend to run the python script later, just the movie file. Thank you.

Comment: I was about to post this as an answer, but I think it doesn't do well enough to solve your problem:
Don't use matplotlib for animations. It performs terribly and doesn't deal well with updates. I strongly recommend having a look at PyQWT an PyQtGraph.org ,which are much better suited for things like these, faster, and not really hard to use. For QWT, you can even use the QtCreator IDE to build interactive applications, and export the GUI as python or python-loadable UI description file.

Comment: Hmm. I'm currently already using Qt in my application. I'll keep that idea in mind. Thanks for the tip.

Keep in mind it doesn't need to be fast. I'd just like to save it as a video (the file format doesn't matter).

Comment: Have a look at GNU Radio's visualizations -- if what you want to visualize is something like a float or complex over time, then they might already have what you're looking for, and GNU Radio comes with an awesome graphical toolkit to generate signal analysis flow graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really just want to save things to a movie, and want to stick to `matplotlib`, no matter how bad it performs computationally:

1. set up your figure: `fig = pyplot.figure(figsize=(w,h), dpi=100)` or so;
2. do your drawing
3. `fig.savefig("{framenumber:06d}.png".format(framenumber=counter))`
4. rinse, repeat

and later use e.g. `mencoder` to convert to a movie:

```
mencoder -o output.mp4 -ovc mpeg4 *.png
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot and get back to you.